# Find joint distribution of same-mean normal variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bayesian

Suppose I have a variable $C$ and a set of $N$ variables $L_1, L_2, ..., L_N$ that are distributed according to:

$$\begin{aligned}
C &\sim \mathcal N \left(\mu, \delta^2 \right) \\
\forall i. L_i | C=c &\sim \mathcal N\left(c, \sigma_i^2 \right)
\end{aligned}$$

That is, conditional on knowing the value of $C$, the $L_i$ are normally independently distributed with mean $c$ and variance $\sigma_i^2$. This implies that the vector $\vec L = (L_1, ..., L_N)^T$ is distributed according to a N-dimensional multivariate normal with mean vector $\vec \mu$ and covariance matrix $\mathbf \Sigma$.

When $N=1$, it is straightforward to see that $L_1 \sim \mathcal N \left(\mu, \delta^2 + \sigma_1^2 \right)$. It seems to me like this should imply that $\vec \mu = (\mu, ..., \mu)^T$, and that the diagonal elements of $\mathbf \Sigma$ should be $\delta^2 + \sigma_i^2$. The off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrix are, of course, *not* zero, since the variables $L_i$ are not independent when I'm not conditioning on $C$.

Is this true, though? Is there a way for me to prove this in a less tedious way than algebraically working everything out? What are the values of the off-diagonal elements?

Comment: "are normally i.i.d. with mean c" is not quite accurate, since they are (conditionally) independent, but not identical because the $\sigma_i$ may differ. You might want to edit this detail.

Comment: You're right, I've fixed that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the $L_i$ as being sums of the form $L_i = C + X_i$, where $X_i$ are independent random variables with $X_i\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma_i^2)$ that are also independent of $C$.
Therefore, for $\mathcal L = (L_1,\dots,L_N)^T$,  $\mathcal C = (C,\dots,C)^T$ and  $\mathcal X = (X_1,\dots,X_N)^T$, you have $\mathcal L = \mathcal C + \mathcal X$.
Note that
$$
\mathcal X\sim \mathcal N\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ \vdots\\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 & & 0 \\ &\ddots& \\ 0& & \sigma_N^2
\end{pmatrix}
\right),
\qquad
\mathcal C\sim \mathcal N\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
\mu\\ \vdots\\ \mu
\end{pmatrix}
,
\delta^2
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &\cdots & 1 \\ \vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\ 1& \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\right)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\mathcal L\sim \mathcal N\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
\mu\\ \vdots\\ \mu
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
\delta^2+\sigma_1^2 &\cdots & \delta^2\\ \vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\ \delta^2& \cdots & \delta^2+\sigma_N^2
\end{pmatrix}
\right)
$$
So, your reasoning is correct and the off-diagonal elements are all equal to $\delta^2$.

Comment: Thank you! Also, minor nitpick, should it be $\mathcal X = (X_i, ..., X_N)^T$?

Comment: You are right, thanks! Edited my answer accordingly.